# Excluding items from a list that are in a certain range using list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I have two lists: `a = [10.0,20.0]` and `b = [1.0,10.0,15.0,20.0,30.0,100.0]`.
How can I remove from list `b` all the elements between `10.0` and `20.0`? Here is what I tried:

```
c = [b[y] for y in range(len(b)) if (b[y] < a[0] or b[y] > a[1])]
```

I expect to get `c = [1.0, 30.0, 100.0]`, but I get `c = [1.0,10.0,15.0,20.0,30.0,100.0]`.

How can I exclude components from a list that are in a certain range by using only list comprehension?

Comment: I got the expected result, you sure that you don't do something like `c=b` somewhere and that is the real problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify by iterating `b`'s elements directly, but your original code works for me, too:

```
a = [10.0, 20.0]
b = [1.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 30.0, 100.0]

c = [x for x in b if x < a[0] or x > a[1]]
# [1.0, 30.0, 100.0]

# Your version:
c = [b[y] for y in range(len(b)) if (b[y] < a[0] or b[y] > a[1])]
# [1.0, 30.0, 100.0]
```

Comment: Thanks, this exactly answered my question, but I asked the wrong question because I wanted to show you guys a simplified version of the issue. I've posted a new more detailed question here, this time I've checked that my solution fails :) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48257451/unable-to-exclude-items-from-a-list-in-a-while-loop-that-are-in-a-certain-rang

Answer (score 2):

Think from the opposite, only includes components that are in a certain range, like this:

`c = [y for y in b if (y < a[0] or y > a[1])]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter`:

```
a = [10.0,20.0]
b = [1.0,10.0,15.0,20.0,30.0,100.0]
new_a = list(filter(lambda x:x < a[0] or x > a[-1], b))
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 30.0, 100.0]
```

Answer (score -2):

Filter function will do this for you :

```
c= filter(lambda x: x<10.0 or x>20.0,b)
```

Comment: 1. Pls, do not use filter and map with lambda, it is just ugly. 2. Using an integer range for equality tests with floats is unpredictable. 3. The contains-check must iterate the range for every element and is therefore bad performance-wise.

Comment: This doesn't even work if `x` is not a whole number.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Definitely not in the general case; for the OP's data, one might get lucky, but still...

Comment: @coldspeed , it works for negative values too.

Comment: Most probably `not in range(10,20)` is not what you think it is.

Comment: @TheVishal Not sure what I'm supposed to glean from that nugget of information. Your code does not work, for say, `12.5`.

Comment: @coldspeed ,  thanks for pointing out sometimes answering other's question clears yours too :)

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer is now identical to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48255963/4909087